# Add circle to line while maintaining drag mechanics

Tags: d3.js, draggable

I'm drawing some small lines that I allow the user to drag in order to make a selection. How do I attach a circle to the center of the line while still maintaining the drag mechanic?

```
var borderData = [
{x : 0, side: "leftBorder"}, {x : rightBorder, side: "rightBorder"}
]

svg.selectAll("line")
.data(borderData)
.enter().append('line')
.attr("x1", function (d) {
    return d.x - 2;
})
.attr("x2", function (d) {
    return d.x - 2;
})
.attr("y1", graphHeight - kernelHeight - 1)
.attr("y2", graphHeight + 1)
.attr("class", function (d) {
    return d.side;
})
.call(dragBorder);
```

I've tried adding the following to the end of the chain, but that doesn't visualize anything.

```
...
.call(dragBorder)
.append('circle')
    .attr("cy", (graphHeight - kernelHeight - 1 + graphHeight + 1)/2)
    .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return d.x; })
    .attr("r", 2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ideas:

1. Call `dragBorder` on a `g` element that acts as a container for your line and the circle.

   ```
   var draggables = svg.selectAll('g.draggableLineCircleWrapper')
     .data(borderData)
       .enter()
       .append('g')
       .classed('draggableLineCircleWrapper')
       .call(dragBorder);

   draggables.append('line')...
   draggables.append('circle')...
   ```
2. Instead of appending a line and a circle, append a path (one element with an intricate shape) and call drag on it.

Comment: I quite like the first idea as that allows me to add more objects if needed. However, I can't seem to append anything to it. If I look at `draggables` in the debugger, I only get the interpretation `False`.

Comment: I've made a quick fiddle to demonstrate the first idea: http://jsfiddle.net/p5ns6jd9/2/